# Gallery blocks break and melt together in WP Gallery function (Safari and Chrome issue)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, block

Im helping out in cleaning up and renovating a website for a friends organisation/art place.

We are working on Gallery of images of the last years of business. Looking at it from a Firefox browser, all looks good. Taking a look at it from any Safari version or Chrome all the images seem to bunch together and overlay in different ways.

See link to one of the gallerys-> http://www.stallbergsgruva.se/2018-2/

I have searched a bunch of forums and threads for this but can't seem to find the answer. Im a beginner at code but can handle it if you add a more thorough description of what code and where to add it, etc.

Thank you in advance! // Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a fixed height to the `li`, if you don't then you won't be able to properly use `object-fit: cover;` Here it is the `css`, also added a `margin-bottom` just to prove

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .wp-block-gallery.columns-3 
  .blocks-gallery-image, 
  .wp-block-gallery.columns-3 
  .blocks-gallery-item {
    width: calc((100% - 32px)/3);
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    height: 290px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the file and the images spread appart and it looks right again. Solved the first part of my problem. 

Second part is about mobile. Is there standard CSS to add for making the site more responsive to mobile and tabs? I notice that the site on mobile is making a lot of errors when trying to read Gallery or parts of the site that include columns. 

Thankfull for all the help I can get!